pseudohydrogen (Z = 1.25) surface passivation in SIESTA
i am dealing with the passivation of a GaAs surface with pseudohydrogens (i.e. hydrogens with nuclear charge Z = 1.25). However, in ATOM, i can only generate PP with Z=1.2 or 1.3, and a bigger problem is: How to write this in the FDF so SIESTA can understand a hydrogen with fractional Z?
